# Probabilistic packet marking content ID field

Tags: ddos, packet

[image]

For Above image:
All routers are using PPM. What will be the content ID field if

1) R1 = mark packet, R2= Mark packet, R3 = Not mark the packet.

2) R1 = Not mark packet, R2= Mark packet, R3 = Not mark the packet.

3) R1 = Not  mark packet, R2= Not Mark packet, R3 = mark the packet.

4) R1 = mark packet, R2= Not Mark packet, R3 = Not mark the packet.

I know that distance will be carry on distance 1 if previously packet has been mark. But this question is bugging me for a long time.